# Simple Java Mail dependencies not in the jar file

Tags: maven, email, jar, dependencies

I used simplejavamail in my maven project. The program can send out the email if I run it from Intellij IDE. But when I create a jar file, and run it from the jar file, then I got class not found for all the simplejavamail classes. And I open the jar, I find out that they are not included in the jar. But all the other dependency classes are there. Any one have meet this issue before?

parts of my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

<build>
    <finalName>my-project-name</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problem.  It appears that the dependencies (Ex. Email, Mailer, EmailBuilder, etc) appear in the org.simplejavamail.api repository.  I'll update you if I find a working solution with v6.4.3 but I have a feeling we may need to include additional dependencies.

Edit:  To at least patch your problem,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The 5.5.1 version still has the classes in the jar.  You can reference this for yourself here:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail/5.5.1/index.html

Then click on the different versions to see what classes exist.

I think something went wrong in their builds since v6.

Let me know if this helps!